# Find an orthonormal basis for the subspace...

Tags: matrices, inner-products, orthonormal, orthogonal-matrices

Consider the real inner product space $M_{2,2}$ $\mathbb{R}$ (The space of 2x2 matrices with real entries), with the inner product as follows:
[image]

(a) Find an orthonormal basis for the subspace U of $M_{2,2}$ $\mathbb{R}$ spanned by:

[image]

(b) Find the orthogonal projection of the matrix

M =  \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 6\\
3 & 2
\end{pmatrix}

onto U.

I honestly have no idea where to start with this question. Any assistance would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

The purpose of [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) is meant to find an orthonormal basis.

Follow the process, when the algorithm involves inner product, use the inner product that your question provided.